# How to Increase Height, Width and Font of the Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have put a Facebook  like button on our web page. But I want to increase its height and width as it is to be displayed on the iPhone.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) you have a list of the attributes provided by facebook.

Among other you have:

```
width - the width of the Like button.
font - the font to display in the button. Options: 'arial', 'lucida grande', 'segoe ui', 'tahoma', 'trebuchet ms', 'verdana'
```